# Hibernate cannot unwrap interface

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss

I need help with

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Hibernate cannot unwrap interface java.sql.Connection
```

I need to unwrap the connection. It's for a migration from glassfish to JBoss eap 7. I don't understand where the problem is. Does JBoss not accept this? Is there another way to do the unwrapping?

I read a lot about unwrapping the connection with `Session`, but my IDE says `Session` not found.

I work with JBoss eap 7 and hibernate 2.1.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Show some code to see what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 7):

Jboss EAP7 supports Hibernate 5.x, not Hibernate 2.x. Use the Hibernate version bundled with specific JBoss EAP release.

```
entityManager.getTransaction().begin();

java.sql.Connection connection = entityManager.unwrap(java.sql.Connection.class);
...
entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
```

---

```
Session hibernateSession = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);

hibernateSession.doWork(new org.hibernate.jdbc.Work() {

    @Override
    public void execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
        // do whatever you need to do with the connection
    }
});
```

see here: http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/EMAPI#Getting_a_JDBC_Connection_from_an_EntityManager